# Material-UI OutlinedInput does not show the startAdornment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Below are the codes. The start adornment does not appear in the textfield. Also, the label does not show any text.

```
<InputLabel>Mobile Number</InputLabel>
            <OutlinedInput
              variant="outlined"
              autoComplete="outlined"
              name="name"
              required
              fullWidth
              label="Enter Mobile Number"
              autoFocus
              inputProps={{
                maxLength: 10,
              }}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">+1 </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
            />
```

[image: This is what it shows in the screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TextField for startAdorment and remove inputlabel and pass your desire label into TextField as a props  :

```
 <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              autoComplete="outlined"
              name="name"
              required
              fullWidth
              label="Enter Mobile Number"
              autoFocus
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">+1 </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
            />
```

or if you want to use OtlinedInput you can pass this as a props :

```
  startAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <AccountCircle />
            </InputAdornment>
          }
```